# Spring-JDBC-Session with Hibernate Multi-tenancy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multi-tenant, spring-session

I am trying to create a spring boot application (scalable in nature) with  Hibernate Multi-tenancy (database per tenant approach), this part is working fine.
I am running this application in a cluster, I am facing issues in HTTP Sessions (need to replicate the HTTP Sessions over other nodes). For this I tried using Spring JDBC Session, but facing issues in setting up that.

I just included Spring Session dependency in gradle file, and applied @EnableJdbcHttpSession annotation to my AppConfigurations.java file.

The issue I am facing is that it give me error that some of the components required bean with name 'dataSource', I tried declaring that too.

I am keeping a map of data sources which keeps data source of each tenant.

After application startup, the map somehow holds only one data source which is the default one (for which I created a bean with name 'dataSource').

I am not sure what I am missing here, or do even Spring-Session support multi-tenancy or not.

Below code displays how I am creating a data-source map which I am further initialising at application startup:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSourceMap" )
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap() {

        Map<String, DataSource> datasources = new HashMap<>();
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("defaultDataSourcePool");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(username);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
        datasources.put(defaultTenant, new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig));

         return datasources;
    }
```

Similarly I also defined a bean which returns a default data-source.

I expect that for each tenant there will be session tables which will hold the session data separately.
Can someone please suggest a way out of it? or may be if someone could share some sample code-base with this kind of integration it would be great.

Comment: Your Map only exists locally on each service instance. Instead of replicating HTTP sessions on all nodes, I think you should consider implementing Oauth2 JWT token. It'd be so much easier and more natural to handle multi-tenancy.

Comment: Multi-tenancy is already working fine, issue is with spring session. I want to replicate HTTP sessions to other cluster nodes.